# UIToolbar Rotation/Animation

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a UIToolbar for an iPad app that is meant to stay at the top of the screen for all orientations.  The UIView that my UIToolbar is part of does not rotate, however.  The UIToolbar DOES rotate, but I'm having trouble getting the rotations to work the way I want...

I can't figure out how to change the size of the toolbar without stretching the contents of the toolbar (setting a scale transformation) or without messing up the transformations (setting the frame or the bounds).

```
- (void)updateOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation animated:(BOOL)animated
{   
    CGAffineTransform toolbarTransform;
    switch(orientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            toolbarTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        toolbarTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-768 / 2 + 44 / 2, 768 / 2 - 44 / 2 + 1024 - 768);
        toolbarTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(toolbarTransform, degreesToRadian(-90));

        break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        toolbarTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(768 / 2 - 44 / 2, 768 / 2 - 44 / 2);
        toolbarTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(toolbarTransform, degreesToRadian(90));

        break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            toolbarTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 1024 - 44);
            toolbarTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(toolbarTransform, degreesToRadian(180));
            break;


        default:
            toolbarTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;
    }

    if(animated)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^
        {
            self.toolbar.transform = toolbarTransform;
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        self.toolbar.transform = toolbarTransform;
    }
}
```

This code mostly positions the toolbar how I want, but what should I do to resize the toolbar without messing up the transformations or stretching the toolbar's contents?  Or maybe I'm approaching this wrong altogether?

edit: Slightly updated my code.  Positioning is correct, just need to resize them somehow...

Comment: You should really take advantage of UIViewController's autorotation features instead of trying to manually hack that together.

Comment: But I don't want my main view to autorotate.  If I can somehow nest this in an extra view that DOES autorotate and somebody can show me how, I'd be just fine with that!  I'm not hacking this together because I want to... :(

Comment: Actually, any form of autorotation will not suffice because other UI elements aren't always in the same orientation as autorotation would put the toolbar in.  I basically HAVE to "hack" this together to achieve the effect that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to create a special UIView (called rotationView) and performing all rotation/translations to that UIView instead of directly to the UIToolbar.  Then, I can change the `toolbar.frame` safely without "messing up" the transformations.